# Does decision-theory tag also includes simple AI decisions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [decision-theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-theory) tag basically the same as [decision-making](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-making)?

For example, can this question:

- [Would Google's self-driving-car stop when it sees somebody with a T-shirt with a stop sign printed on it?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1561/8)

had [decision-making](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-making) tag, however it has been suggested to have one unified [decision-theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-theory).

I'm asking, because decision theory is 'a study of the reasoning', so it's confusing for me whether simple AI decision can be included under this tag as well?